# Insert multiple rows into mysql not working?  I am using php 5, is that why it's not working?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreach, rows

I have a finished script below that goes in insert_dimensions.php file.  Below the dotted line there is another script that goes in a webpage.  These should work to put a bunch of different numbers into a mysql table *on different rows*.  As it is below, the first time the script is run it adds a row to mysql, but it puts a zero in the row.  The 2nd time the script is run, it puts what should have gone in row 1 into row 2.  And it only adds 1 row even though it should be adding more than 1 row.  The rest of the times the script is run it is the same thing.  It's only adding 1 row each time, and it's entering the value that it should have entered the time before.

I have tried many foreach things.  I don't know which page those are supposed to go on because the posts that contain them (from googling) don't usually say on which page to put the codes.  I have tried putting [ ] and other types of brackets with and without $i to the right of addedWeight too.  Nothing has worked.  I have not tried using the variable $key which I see sometimes but I was wondering if that might fix the problem somehow.  In the mysql column it goes into, addedWeight is type INT.  I tried changing it to type varchar but it still didn't work.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","blah","blah");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("blah", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO dimensions (weight_ounces, page_link, session_id)
VALUES
('$_POST[addedWeight]','$_POST[PageLink]','$_POST[SessionID]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<form action="insert_dimensions.php" method="post">
<?php
print "<input type='hidden' name='SessionID' value='" . session_id() . "'>";
$current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");
print "<input type='hidden' name='PageLink' value='" . $current_file_name . "'>";
mysql_connect("localhost", "blah", "blah") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("blah") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query('SELECT weight_ounces FROM dimensions_list WHERE session_id = "' . session_id() . '"'); 
$params = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {     
$params[] = $row['weight_ounces']; 
}
$combinations=getCombinations($params);
function getCombinations($array)
{
    $length=sizeof($array);
    $combocount=pow(2,$length);
for ($i=1; $i<$combocount; $i++)
    {
$binary = str_pad(decbin($i), $length, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $combination='';
        for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++)
        {
            if($binary[$j]=="1")
                $combination+=$array[$j];
        }
        $combinationsarray[]=$combination;
$varw = $combination;
print "<input type='text' name='addedWeight' value='{$varw}'>";
    }
    return $combinationsarray;
}
```

Comment: `Insert multiple rows into mysql not working` - where is the proof? I can't see a *complete SQL query* with multiple inserts you're sending to MySQL.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  If the problem is the mysql statement, can you tell me how it's wrong?

Comment: **That's exactly the problem**: there is NO mysql statement in your question. Just stubs and bits of it. What is complete mysql statement you're sending to database?

Comment: Isn't that this:  $sql="INSERT INTO dimensions (weight_ounces, page_link, session_id) VALUES ('$_POST[addedWeight]','$_POST[PageLink]','$_POST[SessionID]')"; if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

Comment: But It's not SQL statement by any means. It's PHP code. Mysql knows nothing of $_POST and stuff.

Comment: anyway, it can be seen from the PHP code, that resulting SQL contains only one VALUES statement, while you have said you need more. Why don't you add some?

Comment: All the things to be entered have the same name.  I have tried foreach to loop through them but it wouldn't work.  I can get it to enter the same things into multiple rows by putting comma after the values and putting more values.  That doesn't work because I don't know how many values there will be in advance, and they all have the same name.

Comment: Okay so nobody knows how to do this.  Great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems strange. A few comments that might help:

1 - this line has a problem:

```
print "<input type='text' name='addedWeight' value='{$varw}'>";
```

You should probably use

```
print <input type='text' name='addedWeight[]' value='{$varw}'>";
```

The way you have it now, you will pass only the last addedWeight to the php that is inserting in the database. You need to have an array and pass the array.

2 - you probably need a loop in your first script (the one that does the insert). Once you pass the addedWeight as an array, you can so something like

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","blah","blah");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("blah", $con);

$addedWeight = $_POST[addedWeight]; <- load array passed into local variable
$counter = sizeof($addedWeight); <- count the number of items in the array

for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) <- here is the loop that will insert all the elements into the database.
{
  $sql="INSERT INTO dimensions (weight_ounces, page_link, session_id)
  VALUES
  (addedWeight[$i],'$_POST[PageLink]','$_POST[SessionID]')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I hope this makes sense and helps you resolve the issue. If not, please post again.

And one last comment - I would move the function outside the form. I like to keep all my functions in a separate file or at the top or bottom of the script. If you decide to do that the line I discussed above in my item 1 would read something like:

```
print "<input type='text' name=addedWeight[] value='$combinations'>";
```

This is a personal preference of course.

Good luck!